# How to join stream data with a table updated slowly (e.g. once a day)?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

In structured streaming, I need to join stream data with some slow changing data. The slow changing data get updated by daily and might get updated not on a fixed time. The stream data, however, comes at seconds level. If I don't want to load the slow changing data in each micro batch, and also expect to get the latest version of slow changing data once it gets updated, is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [DataStreamWriter.foreachBatch](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter@foreachBatch(function:(org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T],Long)=%3EUnit):org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter[T]) on the stream data and simply [cache](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@cache():Dataset.this.type) and [unpersist](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@unpersist():Dataset.this.type) the slow-changing dataset when needed. Since `foreachBatch` works on the driver (on a separate thread though) it should work.

A very advanced approach, in my opinion, would be to develop a custom data source that would do the "slowing part" itself.

Comment: Thanks Jacek. I expect the cache can be automatically updated once its source is changed, kind of like delta cache (seems open source not support it yet). Right now I'm thinking to cache the slow changing data first and read some time (like a files last modify date) in each micro batch. If the time is changed, then refresh the cache.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Please update us on this with your findings. Please accept the answer if it worked for you. Merci beaucoup!

Comment: I can query a single file to see whether there is change to decide whether the cache should be reloaded. Ideally I should compare current modified time with a recorded time. However this recorded time must be fault-tolerant. It might be too heavy to do something like mapGroupsWithState. For my scenario, I know the file will be modified daily. So I can just compare the last modified date with current date. If it is current date, then there is change and I should update cache, else just use the current cache.

Comment: @processadd Can you show the code (as a separate answer)?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this. I store last modified time of a single file in a variable, then broadcast it, and in foreachBatch I get this time again. If they are different I can refresh the cache. And then I found I don't have to broadcast the variable. If the variable gets the value before foreachBatch, it still keeps original value inside of foreachBatch (for local mode running in intelliJ). Code is like:

```
var latestModified = Files.getLastModifiedTime(Paths.get("/some_file"))
var deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, deltaPath)
var c = deltaTable.toDF.cache()
df
.writeStream
......
.foreachBatch { (df, batchId) =>
    val currentModifiedTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(Paths.get("/some_file"))
    if (!currentModifiedTime.equals((latestModified))){
          c.unpersist()
          c = deltaTable.toDF.cache()
          latestModified = currentModifiedTime
        }
... ...
```